# How to detect the click event for copied code displayed on keyboard -Android

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

How to detect that the user clicked on code displayed on keyboard

Comment: You can't detect the click.  You don't own that view, or the keyboard view.  You could put a textwatcher on the edit text and look for insertion of multiple characters at a time, that's probably your only option.

Comment: in textwatcher , as I am using different edittext for each character, count is always one for me, so this will not work

Comment: No you aren't.  I get that you want to, but when they click it, the keyboard is attached to one and only one edit text.  So it should all be sent to one.  Now that said, your best bet may be to turn your group of edit texts into a custom view and implement your own InputConnection to handle keyboard input on a higher level.  There may be a good solution down that road.